# How to restart MySQL Server after it was shutdow?

Tags: mysql, linux

*I'm sure this question is not duplicated with others.*

OS: macOS 10.14

MySQL version: 8.0.27

I have installed and ran a MySQL Server several months ago, and then I ignored it. Today, I decide to learn MySQL again. So I use the command `mysql` to connect my MySQL Server, do some queries, and everything is fine.

But, for some reason, I decided to shut down the MySQL server and restart it. To shut down, I used this command:

```
mysqladmin shutdown -uroot
```

But after I shut down the MySQL Server, I find I can no longer start it.

Here are some ways I just tried, but all of them don't work.

**Attempt1: mysqld**

```sh
$ mysqld
2021-11-17T07:45:07.200232Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/local/mysql-8.0.27-macos11-x86_64/bin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.27) starting as process 3006
2021-11-17T07:45:07.203326Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file /usr/local/mysql-8.0.27-macos11-x86_64/data/mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitive_test.lower-test
2021-11-17T07:45:07.203335Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/mysql-8.0.27-macos11-x86_64/data/ is case insensitive
2021-11-17T07:45:07.203422Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013276] [Server] Failed to set datadir to '/usr/local/mysql-8.0.27-macos11-x86_64/data/' (OS errno: 2 - No such file or directory)
2021-11-17T07:45:07.203485Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2021-11-17T07:45:07.203680Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/local/mysql-8.0.27-macos11-x86_64/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.27)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

After executed this command, I find it can't start MySQL Server.

**Attempt2: mysqld_safe**

```
$ mysqld_safe
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe: line 653: /usr/local/mysql/data/LSiMac.local.err: No such file or directory
Logging to '/usr/local/mysql/data/LSiMac.local.err'.
2021-11-17T07:46:34.6NZ mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/mysql/data
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe: line 144: /usr/local/mysql/data/LSiMac.local.err: No such file or directory
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe: line 199: /usr/local/mysql/data/LSiMac.local.err: No such file or directory
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe: line 916: /usr/local/mysql/data/LSiMac.local.err: No such file or directory
2021-11-17T07:46:34.6NZ mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/mysql/data/LSiMac.local.pid ended
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe: line 144: /usr/local/mysql/data/LSiMac.local.err: No such file or directory
```

not work.

**Attempt3: mysql.server start**

I found many blogs that say we can start MySQL Server with `mysql.server`, but I can't find this command.

```sh
$ ls
ibd2sdi                       mysql_config                  mysqld-debug
innochecksum                  mysql_config_editor           mysqld_multi
libprotobuf-lite.3.11.4.dylib mysql_migrate_keyring         mysqld_safe
libprotobuf.3.11.4.dylib      mysql_secure_installation     mysqldump
lz4_decompress                mysql_ssl_rsa_setup           mysqldumpslow
my_print_defaults             mysql_tzinfo_to_sql           mysqlimport
myisam_ftdump                 mysql_upgrade                 mysqlpump
myisamchk                     mysqladmin                    mysqlshow
myisamlog                     mysqlbinlog                   mysqlslap
myisampack                    mysqlcheck                    perror
mysql                         mysqld                        zlib_decompress
```

No `mysql.server` in `/usr/local/mysql/bin`.

**Attempt4: restart the computer**

I restart my computer and re-executed the above commands, it doesn't work.

**Attempt5: reinstall**

I have reinstalled it twice, it still doesn't work.

Commands to delete MySQL:

```
sudo rm /usr/local/mysql
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/mysql*
sudo rm -rf /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM
sudo rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/My*
rm -rf ~/Library/PreferencePanes/My*
sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/mysql*
sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/MySQL*
sudo rm -rf /private/var/db/receipts/*mysql*
```

Then install it again:

[image]

**Attempt6: MySQL preference pane**

[image]

It don't work. I remember it worked before.

**A strange thing**

And I find a strange thing when I observe the Activity Monitor that a program called mysqld is continuing to start and be killed.

[image]

Seems there are two unknown programs on my computer, one is trying to start MySQL Server, and the other is continuing to kill it. But I don't have any knowledge about them.

**Goal**

I just want to start a MySQL Server,

Comment: I reinstalled it with homebrew, and started it with `brew services start mysql@5.7 `.